# Unable to install some packages of R in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: r, ubuntu-16.04, bioconductor

I'm unable to run this command in R under ubuntu 16.04

source("http://www.bioconductor.org/biocLite.R").

The error is:

Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :   Couldn't connect to server

Comment: Try using `source("https://www.bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")`.  Something on your system may be protecting you from using the insecure URL.

Comment: @user2554330,  i tried it but nothing work, this command work in R windows system but not in Ubuntu

Comment: Anyone know the solution plz share with me?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? See: https://support.bioconductor.org/p/104731/